# Alternating group $A_5$ has subgroup of order $6$ (group theory)

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, cyclic-decomposition

In my lectures, I've read that $A_5$ $($the alternating group of even length cycles in $S_5$$)$, has a subgroup of order $6$, and the example is: the group generated by $\langle (12) (34), (123)\rangle$.

I don't even understand what group we are generating? Wasn't a cyclic group only generated by one element? Why would this group be of order $6$?

Comment: There are two elements there. One is $(1\ 2)(3\ 4)$ and the other is $(1\ 2\ 3)$. They don't generate a subgroup of order $6$.

Comment: "Even length cycles" is not the right term. $A_5$ is the group of _even permutations_, which are those permutations that are the composition of an even number of transpositions. "Cycles", on the other hand" are a particular kind of permutation, and each cycle of even length is an _odd_ permutation.

Comment: As Lord Shark the Unknown pointed out, that group is not of order six. Try the group generated by $(12)(45)$ and $(123)$ instead. The idea is that $(12)$ and $(123)$ generate a copy of $S_3$. When we use $(12)(45)$ instead of $(12)$ we get an isomorphic group. That $(45)$ part doesn't change the isomorphism type of the group because it commutes with $(123)$. But, it has the effect of turning $(12)$ (as well as the other odd permutations of $S_3$) into even permutations in $S_5$.

Comment: I guess a point is that $A_5$ has no cyclic subgroup of order six, so you have to look for a subgroup isomorphic to $S_3$ instead.

Comment: You can find a copy of $S_{n}$ in $A_{n+2}$ as follows: take an element of $S_n$. If it is already an even permutation, fix the extra two points. If it is an odd permutation, exchange the extra two points. This gives you an even permutation, hence an element of $A_{n+2}$. There are two orbits, and what happens to the final two points just keeps track of whether the permutation of the first $n$ is even or odd - the isomorphism is clear.

Answer (score 1):

https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Twisted_S3_in_A5

Read the above link, there is a subgroup of $A_5$ which is quite similar to $S_3$

Comment: Yep. The group OP mentioned is https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/A4_in_A5